# Pandoc Markdown - insert rendered HTML

Tags: html, latex, pandoc

What is an easy solution to insert rendered HTML (no source code) into a Pandoc Markdown or LaTeX file?

I want to visualize an architecture diagram and tried Tikz but hadn't much success in a days worth trying and I figured HTML essentially can do the same and I am already familiar with it.

Only problem I have, is that I haven't found a good way to import it into Markdown.

What I figured so far:

- PDF seems problematic as you can only insert entrire pages and you don't have labels.
- Images would work I guess but I haven't found any native solution

Comment: To share my personal experience, I usually draw diagrams using [diagrams.net](https://diagrams.net), export as PDF (with options "Crop" and "Transparent Background"), and include them as figures from Pandoc Markdown. Does this workflow by any chance work for your use-case?

Comment: Definitely helps, but it kinda surprises me a bit that there isn't a native solution for this yet.

Answer (score 2):

HTML and PDF are so different that images are the easiest way to bring one into the other. The best choice to embed a vector image in PDF is via another, cropped PDF "image", with a high resolution PNG being the second best option. Open source tools like ImageMagick or GIMP can help you with these transformations.

My slightly more general advice would be to use [Mermaid](https://mermaid-js.github.io) diagrams in combination with [Quarto](https://quarto.org). Mermaid is a very 'Markdown-esque' way of drawing diagrams and is supported by GitHub and the like, so it can even be embedded in README files. Quarto is based on pandoc but is more opinionated and has many addons and improvements built on top (including [support for diagrams](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/diagrams.html)).

Comment: Usually your Browser has little problem converting these formats, but sadly I haven't seen any CLI that can do this in a comparable quality.